# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to figure out this python problem and I keep getting this error:

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'

Here is the problem im supposed to solve: # Write a program that asks the user for the number of males and the number of females registered in a class. The program should display the percentage of males and females in the class.

This is my code:

```
def askuser(prompt):
  userAnswer = None
  while userAnswer is None:
    try:
      userAnswer = float(input("Enter: " + prompt + ":"))
      if userAnswer < 0:
        userAnswer = None
        raise ValueError
    except:  
      print("Number must be greater than 0.")
      return userAnswer

def calcm(male,female):
  return (male / male + female) * 100

def calcf(female,male):
  return (female/ male + female) * 100

def diplay(percent_female,percent_male):
  print("Percent of Females is: ", percent_female)
  print("Percent of Males is: ", percent_male)

def main():
  number_females = askuser("number of females")
  number_males = askuser("number of males")

  percent_female = calcf(number_males,number_females)
  percent_male = calcm(number_males,number_females)

  display(percent_male,percent_female)


main()
```

Thank you!

Comment: The return statement in askuser should go outside of while loop. Copy/paste error?

Comment: One important principle is to catch errors explicitly e.g. `except ValueError` rather than the catch all `except` which will catch any exception. (Including unexpected ones you may not have thought of)

Comment: `return` statement should be outside the `while` loop. Unrelated issue the operator precedence comes into play where you are calculating the percentage. It should be `(male / (male + female)) * 100`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Missing return statement from `try` block in `askuser`
- Typo in `diplay` method name. It should be `display`
- Wrong calculation in percentage
- Wrong order in parameter list for `calcf` and `display` methods

Updated code:

```
def askuser(prompt):
  userAnswer = None
  while userAnswer is None:
    try:
      userAnswer = float(input("Enter: " + prompt + ":"))
      if userAnswer < 0:
        userAnswer = None
        raise ValueError
      return userAnswer
    except:  
      print("Number must be greater than 0.")


def calcm(male, female):
  return (male / (male + female)) * 100

def calcf(male, female):
  return (female / (male + female)) * 100

def display(percent_male, percent_female):
  print("Percent of Females is: ", percent_female)
  print("Percent of Males is: ", percent_male)

def main():
  number_females = askuser("number of females")
  number_males = askuser("number of males")

  percent_female = calcf(number_males,number_females)
  percent_male = calcm(number_males,number_females)

  display(percent_male,percent_female)


main()
```

Output:

[image: output]

Answer (score 1):

Your alignment for return userAnswer is incorrect. It should be outside the except

```
    except:
        print("Number must be greater than 0.")
    return userAnswer
```